# Context for UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, delegates, uicollectionview

This question probably looks similar to some other but I think it is not.

Going straightforward ...

**Is it for you a best practice set an opaque context object (void * / id / AnyObject) to an UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell subclass in general a best practice?**

Why this question? ... You probably know that UITableView / UICollectionView are builded in an asynchronous way, and this carry me to think that this can be a good solution to avoid crashes or wrong data usage.

Let me explain.
Probably the majority of iOS developer encountered at least one time the needs to subclass an UITableViewCell with a delegate object used to pass the cell to react to some interaction on the cell itself.

Doing so the delegate (ViewController) probably will search the index path of the cell to discover the related data object and do some process with the data. Ok but a lot of time it happens that the delegate message is delivered after the tableView was reloaded due to a remote data update but being an asynchronous process old cells are still on screen ...

In the worst case you will crash and in the best case you will act on the wrong data object.

So a solution to this could be, as asked before, an opaque object (context) carried by the cell subclass that will be available to the cell delegate getting back the context from the cell sent to the delegate message.
Obviously due to reuse the cell class must be cleaned up of the context during the prepareForReuse.

In this way TableViewCell **do not know nothing** about the model but it will act as postman for the delegate.

What do you think about?

Answer (score 0):

> but a lot of time it happens that the delegate message is delivered after the tableView was reloaded due to a remote data update but being an asynchronous process old cells are still on screen

You shouldn't get this issue if:

- Your delegate message is sent synchronously on the main queue.
- You deal with model and table view updates synchronously on the main queue.

If you have some delay between your model updating and your table UI reloading, you'll have lots of issues, not just the one you describe.

Essentially, I prefer the method you detailed of looking up the index path etc. over a context object added to the cell.

Comment: Off course the messages to the delegate are sent synchronously on the main thread. What I described can be only seen if the TableView is updated from the remote ... let's think about true live update.

Comment: Once the TableView reload not all dataSource messages are sent in the same run loop. This is how is built the framework. For this reason a reloadData can occur and the user interaction, on the current but old cell, is sent by the framework after the reloadData. It happen not cause of a mistake but because the framework work in this way.